# Print out Javascript array in table

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have this array:

```
var employees = [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
];
```

and I would like to print the entire array out as a html table. How would I accomplish this?

I tried this but could only get the final name the print:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>
<p>
First Name: <span id="fname"></span><br /> 
Last Name: <span id="lname"></span><br /> 
</p> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var txt = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");

for (i=0; i<txt.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].firstName 
    document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].lastName 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You iterate over the array and create DOM elements accordingly, or you use a template engine...

Comment: Why are you creating a JSON string directly in code, then eval-ing it? And if you want a table, why are you using `<span>` elements?

Comment: @Mike: If you're using a library, indicate it next time. Your question is meant to be useful to future readers. If there's no indication that jQuery is used in the question, then jQuery answers don't make sense. This isn't meant to be a one-time localized help for you only. StackOverflow is about creating posts that are useful to the community for years to come.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
var txt = '{"employees":[' +
    '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

// $.parseJSON will parse the txt (JSON) and convert it to an
// JavaScript object. After its call, it gets the employees property
// and sets it to the employees variable
var employees = $.parseJSON( txt ).employees;

var $table = $( "<table></table>" );

for ( var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++ ) {
    var emp = employees[i];
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( emp.firstName ) );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( emp.lastName ) );
    $table.append( $line );
}

$table.appendTo( document.body );

// if you want to insert this table in a div with id attribute 
// set as "myDiv", you can do this:
$table.appendTo( $( "#myDiv" ) );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/aDX7E/

Comment: What if you just want to iterate through an already existing table on an HTML page and write it to the bottom. How can you append the table data to the already existing web document?

Answer (score 10):

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var firstNameCell = row.insertCell(-1);
  firstNameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employees[i].firstName));
  var lastNameCell = row.insertCell(-1);
  lastNameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employees[i].lastName));
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: can I ask why you are using (-1) in table.insertRow() ? why it's (-1) ? Same for insertCell

Answer (score 2):

A reusable JSON to table conversion solution for objects in an array type of data structure. Object properties are inserted at the header cells and the values are inserted at the data cells. Sorry for my unorthodox indenting but it makes me  feel comfortable with functional programming.

```js
var employees = [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
],
goods = [
{ "ID":"0001" , "Description":"Cool Table", "Price":"499" , "Color":"Green" }, 
{ "ID":"0002" , "Description":"Ceramic Vase", "Price":"120" , "Color":"Beige" }, 
{ "ID":"0003" , "Description":"Titanium Ashtray", "Price":"999" , "Color":"Titanium Color" },
{ "ID":"0004" , "Description":"Story Book", "Price":"1" , "Color":"Yellow" },
{ "ID":"0005" , "Description":"Chair", "Price":"120" , "Color":"Pink" }
],


tableMaker = o => {var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
                   rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                   : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                       rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),rowMaker(keys,"th"));
                   return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
                  };

document.write(tableMaker(employees));
document.write(tableMaker(goods));
```