# Table sorting with random values

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Im new at javascript/Html and i have a tabe with values that I want to sort. The question is how do i make a cycle for column / rows so they can stay the same number.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Table() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, attrib;
  list = document.getElementById("picks");
  attrib = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  switching = true;
   while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;
          if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
               shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
        attrib[i].parentNode.insertBefore(attrib[i + 1], attrib[i]);
              switching = true;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="Table()">Sort</button>

<table id="picks">
    <tr>
        <td><p>Sam</p></td>
        <td><p>Leo</p></td>
        <td><p>Teo</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Ann</p></td>
        <td><p>Susan</p></td>
        <td><p>Sasha</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Yu</p></td>
        <td><p>Harry</p></td>
        <td><p>Katy</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried making a for cycle for the document.getElementsByTagName("TR"); and didnt really got to the end result.
Im using a column as an argument and its rearranging the whole talbe.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the same table shape (rows/columns)?
Why don't you just grab all the `<td>`s, sort them, then push all the output into the number of rows/columns you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your data in an array, sort them and display them from the array.

Using JQuery will make DOM manipulation much easier.

Look at the accepted answer:
[Print out Javascript array in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958641/print-out-javascript-array-in-table)